# Call a function with a variable after other ends (javascript / jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

My variable `variablex` is undefined, how am I supposed to do it right?

Code:

```
check_content();

function htmlOutput(html){
    console.log("first function works")
}

function check_content(){

        var variablex = "content";
        var html = "foo"

        $.when( htmlOutput(html) ).done(function(variablex) {
        console.log(variablex);
        })
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48zjb44z/1/)**

Comment: because variablex collides with variablex in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48zjb44z/2/)**

You should remove it from the callback `done` because it will override the variable :

```
 $.when( htmlOutput(html) ).done(function() {
    console.log(variablex);
})
```

**NOTE :** As @jfriend00 mentioned in the comment bellow there's no reason to use `$.when()` in your case.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The example I used is a bit different than what I have in my code, the function htmloutput changes the `.html()` of a div. I'm yet to know if it makes a difference, but I guess I do not know the real use of `$.when()`

Comment: I had a bat time deciding which answer should be marked as correct. Even though @jfriend00 gave a better detailed answer and helped me to understand the real meaning for `$.when()`, I think my biggest struggle here was to find out the problem with the variable instead of what would be better for my code.

So, thank you both and hope you don't take it in a bad way @jfriend00, thank's again!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of what to use `$.when()` for is just wrong.  It has no place in this context and thus it does not do what you apparently are expecting it to do.

`$.when()` requires one or more promises passed to it.  It does not have any magical powers to know when some function in it is done.

Plus your `htmlOutput(html)` function call doesn't even return anything so I have no idea how you expect `$.when( htmlOutput(html) ).done(...)` to actually have a value.

This explains why your current code does not do what you seem to be expecting.  If you want further help, you will have to describe what you're trying to accomplish and why you're using `$.when()` with a synchronous function that doesn't return a promise.

You can remove the `$.when()` entirely and just have this because synchronous functions like `htmlOutput()` block until complete so there's no reason to use promises or `$.when()` with them:

```
function htmlOutput(html){
    console.log("first function works")
}

function check_content(){

    var variablex = "content";
    var html = "foo"

    htmlOutput(html);
    console.log(variablex);
}

check_content();
```

Comment: I surely didn't explain right. I didn't put it in the JSFiddle, but in my code the function htmlOutput(html) changes the .html() of a div. I thought $.when + .done would run the function after the div has its html changed... At least it looks like it...

Comment: I pressed enter before I typed the whole answer, my bad, just edited it too.

Comment: @xickoh - There is no reason to use `$.when()`.  Changing the HTML of  a div is a synchronous operation.  You can just call one function, then the next.  No reason for `$.when()` in that case.  Next time, please show more of the actual situation in your question (not just a dummy example) so we can answer the real question more completely.  Also, very important to know that `$.when()` is ONLY useful when passing it multiple promises.  Otherwise, it serves no benefit.